# Read and edit python 2 file with python 3

Tags: python

How can I read python 2 files on python 3 IDLE? I need to write a script where I read certain python 2 files that are given to me and convert them into python 3. I have to do this on the IDLE and change the python 2 manually and save it as a py3 file. I thought I can use `f= file.open("somepy2file.py" , "w")`. I'm given 5 py2 files so I only have to change the things specifically to these py files. For example just changing `print "a"` to `print ("a")`.

Comment: `"w"` is for write. You need to open for read first with `"r"` (which is the default). Then create a new file to write your translation to Python3.

Comment: @JulienBernu thank you, I just tried that and it doesn't give me an error anymore. But when I do .readlines() it prints []. Why is that ? Thanks for the help

Comment: Because your file is empty.

Comment: The fact that you write and/or run your code with IDLE is not relevant to the coding problem.

Answer (score 1):

A simple google search will reveal that there exists a script called `2to3.py` in your `Tools/Scripts` folder. From the command line simply type `python.exe [path to your python folder]/Tools/Scripts your-script.py`

Comment: I'm not allow to use that script.

Comment: So this is homework, you'll have to figure it out yourself, it seems.

Comment: Yes it's homework but I just trying to figure out why can't I read it . I know how to do everything else